# Difficulty installing a dependency required to compile Doom 64 EX

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, dependencies, compiling

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 on Crouton. My goal here is to compile and install Doom 64 EX. I am trying to follow the github guide seen here:

https://github.com/svkaiser/Doom64EX

Under the bold section for prepare dependencies under Ubuntu I am stuck on the final command.  Whenever I enter

```
$ sudo apt install git cmake libsdl2-dev libsdl2_net-dev zlib1g-dev libpng-dev
```

into the command terminal it gives me this.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libpng12-dev' instead of 'libpng-dev'
E: Unable to locate package libsdl2_net-dev`
```

I am unsure where to go from here.

Perhaps unrelated but one reddit user noted that one of the command terminal lines given earlier in the guide had a typo in it.  In the guide it reads

```
$ sudo add-apt repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

When it should read

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

Again perhaps unrelated but more typos may persist on the github page.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Manual Installation**

If you wish to install `libsdl2-net-2` manually in Ubuntu, download the `deb` file from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/libsdl2-net-2.0-0/2.0.0+dfsg1-2).

> This is a small, low-level, cross-platform networking library, that
>   can be used  with the Simple DirectMedia Layer library.
>
> This package contains the shared library.

Comment: Can this also be done for the `zlib1g-dev` and the `libpng-dev`?, or were those also included in the link that you provided?  Ty.

Comment: Just searched the package name for you;  both work okay! `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libpng-dev`

Comment: Just to clarify that I understood correctly before I go ahead and do so I am going to get the `deb` that you linked above and install that by hand in Nautilus, and then I enter the two command lines that you just gave me in the terminal and that will complete all of the required dependencies that I was trying to get?

Comment: The `deb` file is for the package `libsd12-net-2`, and the other two packages are still obtainable via `apt-get`, `The following NEW packages will be installed:   zlib1g-dev` as an example. You could use `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb` for your first package. If it works, please mark answer as correct.

Comment: I will mark it as correct if it works.  You lost me a bit on the `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb` I am sorry but for further clarification I was a bit unsure how that pertains to the first package.  Ty.

Comment: Let's assume you've downloaded the `deb` to `/home/undyinglight/Downloads` as `test.deb`. In the terminal run `sudo dpkg -i /home/undyinglight/Downloads/test.deb` to install.

Comment: I just tried it, what the command line gave back is a bit too long to copy and paste in here but if I understood it correctly it was saying that the `deb` needed a dependency of its own before it could be installed.  The same thing was being said for the `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev` and the `sudo apt-get install libpng-dev`

Comment: Did it mention what dependency? `sudo apt-get update` with a `-f` and clean might aid. If the output too large, use pastebin

Comment: Where I am at currently.   I went through some of the steps on github again for setting up dependencies on Ubuntu.  This time I believe that the `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libpng-dev` worked correctly.  That only leaves the libsdl2-dev and the libsdl2_net-dev.  When I try to `sudo dpkg -i /home/undyinglight/Downloads/test.deb` I get the following https://pastebin.com/Xq0kkigQ